# Move [eax+4] in VS

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I can't compile this, how should I move [eax+4] to y in Visual Studio?

```
float x, y, z;

__asm
{
    mov x,      eax
    mov y,      [eax+4]
    mov z,      [eax+8]
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Error  1   error C2424: '+' : improper expression in 'second operand'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining a variable inside c++ inline assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396265/defining-a-variable-inside-c-inline-assembly)

Comment: What do you mean “can't compile”? What does the compiler say?

Comment: You know `[eax+4]` uses EAX as a pointer, right?  If `eax` holds a valid pointer, it's unlikely to also be useful as a `float` bit-pattern.  I think this is an XY problem and you're probably looking for `add eax,4` / `cvtsi2ss xmm0, eax` / `movss y, xmm0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `eax` as a pointer, so storing that bit-pattern into `float x` seems unlikely.  Perhaps you meant to copy 3 floats from memory at `[eax+0]`, +4, and +8?

@RaymondChen is right, you can use a temporary register to transfer it.  The obvious choice is to pick ECX or EDX as a temporary;  those along with EAX are call-clobbered so using them won't force the compiler to save/restore them in the function containing your asm block.

Even though the values are `float`, you can copy them with 32-bit integer registers instead of through XMM0 or an x87 register; you're not doing FP math on them.

```
mov   ecx, [eax]
mov   x, ecx            // you probably want this, not  mov x, eax
mov   ecx, [eax+4]
mov   y, ecx
mov   ecx, [eax+8]
mov   z, ecx
```

If you knew `x` and `y` were contiguous, you could copy 8 bytes at once with an XMM register.

Comment: Displacement is *not* only possible with ebp and ebx. Not even in 16bit, where si and di can appear with a displacement and without bp or bx as well.

Comment: In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes) there's a clear summary of all possible addressing modes for 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit x86 processors.

Comment: @harold: although correct, esi and edi are not called "base"s but "index"es in those addressing modes. maybe i should have worded it as "only ebp and ebx are allowed to be bases for displacement" to be accurate.

Comment: @ssg then it still isn't true in 32bit. Everything can be a base.

Comment: This is overcomplicated (use tmp regs like ECX, not push) and doesn't address the fact that valid pointers are unlikely to be useful when stored into `float` variables.  (`mov x, eax`)

Comment: @PeterCordes you're absolutely right. i don't know why my answer got accepted though. i guess i pointed OP in the right direction. i replaced this with a simpler code. not sure whether it would compile in VS syntax though.

Comment: Yuck, why would you want to use stack memory for the temporary instead of ECX or EDX?  Also, don't remove the explanation for *why* you need this: you can't mov mem,mem

Comment: @PeterCordes Please feel free to edit my answer to your liking, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The MOV instruction cannot move memory to memory. Check your favorite assembly language reference for more details on the rules for each instruction. If something is not explicitly listed as permitted, then it is not allowed. You can't just make up stuff. Processors are very picky.

Answer (score -2):

```
float x, y, z;

__asm
{
    mov x,      eax
    push        eax
    mov eax,    [eax+4]
    mov y,      eax
    pop         eax
    mov eax,    [eax+8]
    mov z,      eax
}
```

Comment: This is a small optimization over Sedat's answer, but without the explanation so it's not a very good answer.  And it could be more efficient by loading into a different register, e.g. `mov edx, [eax+4]` avoids the need for push/pop.

Comment: sure mov edx, [eax+4] would save 2 bytes on push/pop but only in case that edx is not used at this moment, otherwise u should make push/pop for edx as well

Comment: EDX is call-clobbered; functions that use it don't need to save/restore it.  Using it in inline asm might make the compiler spill/reload something it would otherwise have kept in EDX across the asm block, but most likely not. 
 Also, most of the time we care about performance, not code-size, so what matters are the 2 uops for those instructions, and the extra store/reload latency of the pointer before it's ready for the load from `[eax+8]`.  Also that this code is doing a lot of store/reload so those execution units are going to be busy.

Comment: EDX is call-clobbered in case of function call in you case it has to be stored/reloaded outside of the asm block, and anyway 2 times push/pop is less then one

Comment: All code is inside of *some* function.  After inlining it might not be the same function in the source.  Anyway no, it doesn't have to be stored/reloaded outside the asm block.  MSVC will just let it get destroyed.  See a real example here: https://godbolt.org/z/gecwkE shows x86 MSVC 19.22, and clang 9.0 `-O3 -fasm-blocks`.  If whatever value was in EDX before the asm block isn't needed afterwards, the value can just die there.  Anyway, optimizing this asm is a bit crazy, it makes no sense to store a pointer to a `float`, and using MSVC inline asm forces inputs/outputs to bounce through memory

Comment: @Peter Corde define your function as __fastcall with two arguments to see how edx is used e.g. foo(arg1, arg2 ) then asm block then touch arg 2

Comment: Ok sure, of course you can construct cases where the compiler makes worse code.  But `_asm` inside a function with register args is not officially supported by MSVC!  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a8ss06.aspx and Ross's comment on [What is the difference between 'asm', '\_\_asm' and '\_\_asm\_\_'?](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/59576185).  MSVC inline asm is mostly pointless for efficiency unless you're wrapping a whole loop, but you might as well keep the asm statement itself as compact as possible; hopefully the compiler *won't* have to save/restore a register.

Comment: In practice MSVC and clang both just pick a register that the inline asm doesn't write.  In this case `eax`, which the inline asm uses read-only.  So we just get 2 extra `mov` instructions; cheaper than push/pop.  https://godbolt.org/z/KSGSh6.  Or it would be just one `mov` if the code after the `asm` block didn't care what register it was in.  I used a tailcall of another `__fastcall` function so it had to be ECX.

Comment: @ Peter Cordes __fastcall function with 2 args should use ECX and EDX in 32bit MSVC

Comment: That's correct.  Therefore it's not safe to use `_asm` in such a function, according to Microsoft.  (Although their current compiler seems to handle the case I tried; look at the Godbolt link where I used `ecx` as the tmp in the asm, and only one function arg.)